# Caching database query results on webserver in a database using .net cache provider classes

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, caching

I have an e-commerce like site to build and given the frequency and volume of request that we would have to handle, its best to incorporate caching in our code base from the beginning itself. I read about .net 4's system.runtime.cache and system.web.cache. These classes provide cache at application level. There is also a possibility of implementing our own custom provider using outputcacheprovider interface.

Now I was thinking that it would be better to have a small db server at webserver itself which will cache the results of frequently made sql queries which could be server to the web page and will save me a round trip to actual db server and db access.

I went through a lot of blogs but i didnt find anything directly related to this.
Now I have a few questions:
1. Is it good to have small dbserver at webserver to handle frequent queries ?
2. Is it possible to implement this kind of caching using outputcacheprovider ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't really do a lot other than put added load on your web server. The only time it might make a difference is if there sufficient lag on your network between the web server & db server to make it worthwhile.

The point of caching is you're holding the data in a processed form in a fast medium, ie memory.

You're better of looking at something like appfabric or memcache to provide your caching rather than a db.

Also, bear in find the difference between caching & outputcaching. caching is holding data in memory for your application to use as it needs. OutputCaching is storing the generated output for a page meaning that future requests get the cached version & you don't have to generate the page every time.

Comment: Also, you have to be careful what you are cacheing and where. If you insert any data in asp.net cache, then every thread in your app domain will have access to it. If you insert data in Asp.net session then only the current user's context can access that data. So, I insert things like country lists and state lists in asp.net cache and user executed query results or details data in asp.net session, if needed.

Comment: @NabheetSandhu could you provide me a link to any article that presents how to use session cache and asp.net cache and difference between them. as i said i havent yet started coding and i am only looking to finalize everything before i jump in. Thanks.

Comment: "...only time it might make a difference is if there [is] sufficient lag on your network..." Not necessarily. Database result caching (aka SQL dependency notifications) can also help reduce number of calls (round trips) to the database server so the SQL queries don't have to compile and run at all, thus reducing CPU and I/O load on both servers (web and SQL) in addition to the network traffic/bottlenecks and rebuilding the object graph each request.

Comment: @Mufasa in general yes, that's true. in the context of the above question, it wouldn't make a difference as I was referring to the OP suggesting keeping a mirrored copy of the data on a local sql server. You therefore wouldn't get all the goodness you suggested.